# parse XML message using SPEL

Tags: spring-el, spring-integration-dsl

In my Spring Integration pipeline I am getting a XML payload and depending on the value of the attributes in the XML I have to generate a key and publish it to kafka.

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(kafkaListenerContainer))
                .wireTap(ACARS_WIRE_TAP_CHNL) // Log the raw message
                .enrichHeaders(h ->h.headerFunction(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, m -> {
                        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
                        Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("payload.Body.toString()");
                        //Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("m.payload.Body.ACIFlight.fltNbr.toString()");
                        String flightNbr = expression.getValue(String.class);
                        header.append(flightNbr);
                        return header.toString();
                })) 
                .get();
```

XMl is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.exmaple.com/FlightLeg">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns1:eventHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.exmaple.com/header" eventID="659" eventName="FlightLegEvent" version="1.0.0">
            <ns1:eventSubType>FlightLeg</ns1:eventSubType>
        </ns1:eventHeader>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns1:ACIFlight xmlns:ns1="http://ual.com/cep/aero/ACIFlight">
            <flightKey>1267:07042020:UA</flightKey>
            <fltNbr>1267</fltNbr>
            <fltLastLegDepDt>07042020</fltLastLegDepDt>
            <carrCd>UA</carrCd>
        </ns1:ACIFlight>
    </ns0:Body>
</ns0:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get the fltNbr from this xml payload using spel. Please suggest

**Updated**

```
String flight = XPathUtils.evaluate(message.getPayload(), "/*[local-name() = 'fltNbr']",XPathUtils.STRING);
String DepDate = XPathUtils.evaluate(message.getPayload(), "/*[local-name() = 'fltLastLegDepDt']",XPathUtils.STRING);
return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("key", flight+DepDate).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XPath Header Enricher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/xml.html#xml-xpath-header-enricher).

XPath is also available as a Spel function, but you'd be better off using the enricher in this case.

```
public class XPathHeaderEnricher extends HeaderEnricher {
```

Here's a test case...

```java
    @Test
    public void convertedEvaluation() {
        Map<String, XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor> expressionMap =
                new HashMap<String, XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor>();
        XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor processor = new XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor(
                "/root/elementOne");
        processor.setHeaderType(TimeZone.class);
        expressionMap.put("one", processor);
        String docAsString = "<root><elementOne>America/New_York</elementOne></root>";
        XPathHeaderEnricher enricher = new XPathHeaderEnricher(expressionMap);
        Message<?> result = enricher.transform(MessageBuilder.withPayload(docAsString).build());
        MessageHeaders headers = result.getHeaders();
        assertThat(headers.get("one")).as("Wrong value for element one expression")
                .isEqualTo(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Gary for your help. For extracting multiple attributes and then appending it as a kafka header key do we need to have multiple XPathExpressionEvaluatingHeaderValueMessageProcessor

Comment: Yes; one processor per header needs to be added to the map.

Comment: Thank you Gary, please suggest how can i add all the header attributes into kafka key header. Say I extract 2 attributes from the xml and then I want to append these 2 attributes and create the kafka key header

Comment: For more complex scenarios, you can use Spel expressions instead, utilizing the `#xpath` SpEL function - see [#xpath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/xml.html#xpath-spel-function). `enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(...)`.

Comment: Thank you Gary I am using XPathUtils.evaluate to get the value of the attributes from XML and appending it. Then using MessageBuilder.setHeader to set the kafka key.Please let me know if this approach looks fine-                                String flight = XPathUtils.evaluate(message.getPayload(), "/*[local-name() = 'fltNbr']",XPathUtils.STRING);
String DepDate = XPathUtils.evaluate(message.getPayload(), "/*[local-name() = 'fltLastLegDepDt']",XPathUtils.STRING);
return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message).setHeader("key", flight+DepDate).build();

Comment: Please don't put code in comments; it's too hard to read; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. The SpEL function uses `XPathUtils` under the covers. So, yes.

Comment: Sorry Gary for putting the code in the comments, I have updated my question with the snippet - Please see if this looks correct. Thank you

Comment: From a Spring perspective it looks ok but I can't comment on the validity of the XPath. I am not an expert on XPath itself.